# put one div above the other in media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

So I have two divs, on big screens they are side by side.

```
<div1> <div2>
```

On smaller screens, I want to get

```
<div2>
<div1>
```

I guess I could remove the `float` and put `width:100%` and `display:block;`. And the two divs are the one above the other, we are half-way there. But how I put the `div2` above the `div1` ? I tried putting opposite floats, one div floats right, the other left, but no luck.

Is negative margin a legit solution for a responsive web app where everything is fluid? I cannot get the `div1` to go under the other, they always overlap. Or there is a more solid solution? Setting `display: table-header-group;` worked in the fiddle, but not in my project and I dont understand why. Doing it without CSS3 would be awesome.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slevin/sk99xqdd/)

Thank you

Comment: Use Bootstrap or similar responsive framework to make this easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk99xqdd/1/)

I added `float:right;` to both divs and i changed there order on the page like so:

```
<div id="amir">amir</div>
<div id="jake">jake</div>
```

and there is a second version when amir is on top [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sk99xqdd/1/)

Comment: Yes, but I want this to display jake first and then amir.

Comment: Sorry I got confused. I will check your answer and let you know. A million times sorry.

Comment: @slevin it's ok,I fixed it know so that there is no need to change the div's order.

Comment: Thanks [works fine](https://media.giphy.com/media/ClcWrARkrq1GM/giphy.gif)

Comment: @ShlomiHaver Thanks, I used your answer and helped me. But I have a problem with the container. If you want to check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291930/position-absolute-gives-parent-no-height).  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You just have to swap the position of your HTML Divs as :

`<div id="amir">Amir</div>
 <div id="jake">Jake</div>`

Here is the [fiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/vinayofficial/7hk8udqy/)