# position absolute gives parent no height

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, css-position

I have two `div`s in a parent `div`. They render side by side

```
<image><info>
```

but on smaller screens I want them to render one under the other and swap positions, like

```
<info>
<image>
```

So, their real order in html is

```
<info>
<image>
```

and they both have `float:right` so they appear swapped and side by side. On smaller screens they both have `float:none` and thet appear one under the other as they should. I used Shlomi's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286483/put-one-div-above-the-other-in-media-queries) and it works fine.

The problem.

When horizontal, I wan to align the `div`s on the left, but due to the `float:right`, they align right.

So I thought I give the container `position:relative` and the children `position:absolute` , so then I can do `left:0;` and `right:0`. This make the container have zero height and a vertical scrollbar appears. If I remove the `position:absolute` its back to normal, but no left aligned.

So either I can use `position:absolute` and fix container's height or my solution is stupid and maybe you suggest something else.

My code right now

```
#container{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   display: block;
   margin-top: 30px ;  
   padding-bottom: 38px;
   clear: both;
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;
}

#image{
    display: block;
    height: 221px;
    width : auto;
    float: right; 
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

#info{
    width:-moz-calc(100% - 331px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 331px);width: calc(90% - 331px);    
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's expected. Absolute positioned elements are taken out of the document flow and so do not add to their relative parents dimensions,

Comment: @user2860857 please post a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
float: left;
```

instead :)

Here is the fiddle of Shlomi updated :

https://jsfiddle.net/sk99xqdd/4/

I'm not sure if it answers your question ...